# Moving the code one coloumn to the left

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code and now my excel template has changed (the first column is no longer in need), is there a way to move the entry code 1 column to the left instant of correcting it step by step?

For example(This is the old code):

```
 .Range("I1:J1") = Array("CHECK", "KEY")
```

Now I need to change it to:

.Range("H1:I1") = Array("CHECK", "KEY")

But it's a very long code and I want to know if there's any way do to it easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest simply using the built in Search & Replace function `( Ctrl + f )`. Put something like

`.Range("I1:J1")`

into the "Find What" field and

`.Range("H1:I1")`

into the "Replace With" field.
 If you're really lazy you could hit the Replace All button, but this can be dangerous as in possibly changing parts you didn't want to change. However, using the Replace button and going through all entries can be fairly fast even in a longer code, and this way you can check with each entry if it's really correct to change it.

Comment: Thanks, and what i can do for formulas? like those: `        .Range("A2:A" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC8&RC13&RC17"
        .Range("B2:B" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'CSI Plan ww'!C10:C14, 2, 0)"
        .Range("C2:C" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'CSI Plan ww'!C10:C14, 3, 0)"
        .Range("D2:D" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'CSI Plan ww'!C10:C14, 4, 0)"
        .Range("E2:E" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'CSI Plan ww'!C10:C14, 5, 0)"`

Comment: You have to be a bit creative and change your search & replace criterias accordingly.   Put  RC1 in "Find What" and RC2 in "Replace With" and so on. It may take a little bit more work if you have many different cases to address.

Comment: I hope I could be of help! Please remember to accept my answer as correct, if it was useful enough to you!